# Como definir uma fonte nova fonte(externa) para um JtextPane

Tags: java

Eu tenho um `JTextPane` e quero definir uma nova fonte(achei na internet) para ele.
Vi diversos tutoriais, porem nenhum deles conseguiu definir a fonte, eu gostaria de fazer da forma mais simples possível.

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("A.ttf"));
```

Eu tentei isso, porem da o erro

```
Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

Comment: ["Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit sup..."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6772724/4056678).

Comment: Verifica se é isto que precisas http://stackoverflow.com/a/5652385/3792998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consigo reproduzir o problema através do código que você apresentou.
Como apontado pelo re22, parece que o problema é de **tratamento de exceção - o seu código funciona**.
Segue uma amostra (note que ela não é exatamente "correta", muitos detalhes foram omitidos para reduzir o código):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TesteFonte extends JPanel {

    JTextArea textArea;
    String texto = "Testando uma fonte diferente!";

    public TesteFonte() throws Exception {

        super(new GridBagLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);

        Font minhaFonte = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
            new File("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Downloads\\oliver__.ttf"))
            .deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 28);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        add(textArea, c);

        textArea.setFont(minhaFonte);
        textArea.append(texto + "\n");
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Teste de Fonte");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new TesteFonte());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Aqui está o resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Eu sugiro que você inclua o seu código inteiro na pergunta - se ele for muito grande, que você tente reduzí-lo, mas de maneira que ele **ainda possa ser executado**. Assim, programadores experientes (não é o meu caso), resolverão casos como este num piscar de olhos!

Código original: [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextDemoProject/src/components/TextDemo.java)

Código pra inserção de fonte: [SOen (Neil Derno)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27088079/1579771)

Fonte usada no texto de exemplo: ["Oliver" (dafont)](http://www.dafont.com/oliver.font)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado